# Swift: Button Enabling Not Working?

Tags: swift, uibutton, int, uitextfield, boolean

I have a button that is disabled in my view controller. I have IBActions for when two text fields are edited. I am trying to enable the button when two text fields both contain integers. I have tried to do this, but whenever I run the ios simulator, the button stays disabled even when I put integers into each text field. Why is it staying disabled? I am new to swift, so please help me out. Here is the code for my entire project:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var calculatorButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var inspirationLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var beginningLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var calculatorContainer: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var answer1Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var yourWeightTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var calorieNumberTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var menuExampleButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var aboutButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var calculateButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
    yourWeightTextField.delegate = self
    calorieNumberTextField.delegate = self
    calculateButton.enabled = false
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func calculatorButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    calculatorContainer.hidden = false
    inspirationLabel.hidden = true
    beginningLabel.hidden = true
    menuExampleButton.hidden = true
    aboutButton.hidden = true
}

@IBAction func yourWeightEditingDidEnd(sender: AnyObject) {
    yourWeightTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

@IBAction func calorieNumberEditingDidEnd(sender: AnyObject) {
    calorieNumberTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

var yourWeightFilled = false
var calorieNumberFilled = false

func yourWeightTextFieldValueValidInt(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // Find out what the text field will be after adding the current edit
    let text = (yourWeightTextField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    if let intVal = text.toInt() {
        self.yourWeightFilled = true
    } else {
        self.yourWeightFilled = false
    }
    return true
}
func calorieNumberTextFieldValueValidInt(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // Find out what the text field will be after adding the current edit
    let text = (calorieNumberTextField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    if let intVal = text.toInt() {
        self.calorieNumberFilled = true
    } else {
        self.calorieNumberFilled = false
    }
    return true
}

@IBAction func yourWeightTextFieldEdited(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.yourWeightFilled && self.calorieNumberFilled {
        self.calculateButton.enabled = true
    }
}

@IBAction func calorieNumberTextFieldEdited(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.yourWeightFilled && self.calorieNumberFilled {
        self.calculateButton.enabled = true
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your delegate methods are a bit mixed up -- they have to be named exactly what the caller expects, or they won't be found, so `yourWeightTextFieldValueValidInt()` and `calorieNumberTextFieldValueValidInt()` aren't being called at all. Instead you'll need to handle the edits to *both* text fields in a single method:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // Find out what the text field will be after adding the current edit
    let text = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    if textField == yourWeightTextField {
        yourWeightFilled = text.toInt() != nil
    } else if textField == calorieNumberTextField {
        calorieNumberFilled = text.toInt() != nil
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Ok, that makes much more sense. Thank you!